# joblib parallel loop is throwing "OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument" for n_jobs > 1

Tags: python-3.x, parallel-processing, path, spyder, joblib

I am trying to create a parallel loop using the joblib library, but I got this error message: `OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument` whenever I insert n_job > 1 (it works for 1, but that is not exactly why i am doing it). I get that it has something to do with the relative/absolute path of Windows, but I am only using the example code:

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
def process(i):
    return i * i
    
results = Parallel(n_jobs = 2)(delayed(process)(i) for i in range(10))

print(results)
```

Any idea how to fix it?

I am using Windows 11, Spyder 5.4.3, Python 3.8.10

Full console output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File C:\Program Files\Spyder\pkgs\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File d:\projekty\pyvista\untitled1.py:12
    results = Parallel(n_jobs = 2)(delayed(process)(i) for i in range(10))

  File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py:1008 in __call__
    n_jobs = self._initialize_backend()

  File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py:775 in _initialize_backend
    n_jobs = self._backend.configure(n_jobs=self.n_jobs, parallel=self,

  File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\joblib\_parallel_backends.py:506 in configure
    self._workers = get_memmapping_executor(

  File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\joblib\executor.py:20 in get_memmapping_executor
    return MemmappingExecutor.get_memmapping_executor(n_jobs, **kwargs)

  File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\joblib\executor.py:42 in get_memmapping_executor
    manager = TemporaryResourcesManager(temp_folder)

  File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\joblib\_memmapping_reducer.py:535 in __init__
    self.set_current_context(context_id)

  File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\joblib\_memmapping_reducer.py:539 in set_current_context
    self.register_new_context(context_id)

  File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\joblib\_memmapping_reducer.py:564 in register_new_context
    self.register_folder_finalizer(new_folder_path, context_id)

  File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\joblib\_memmapping_reducer.py:594 in register_folder_finalizer
    resource_tracker.register(pool_subfolder, "folder")

  File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\joblib\externals\loky\backend\resource_tracker.py:178 in register
    self.ensure_running()

  File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\joblib\externals\loky\backend\resource_tracker.py:99 in ensure_running
    if self._check_alive():

  File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\joblib\externals\loky\backend\resource_tracker.py:170 in _check_alive
    self._send('PROBE', '', '')

  File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\joblib\externals\loky\backend\resource_tracker.py:197 in _send
    nbytes = os.write(self._fd, msg)

OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

Comment: Hello ben, thanks for the answer. The problem it that I cannot run even the basic example with more then one core. Everything else is just related info. What other information should I add?